# Compare vlaues based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df consisting of horse racing data. The columns are as follows;

```
       'distance_(y)', 'race_type', 'class', 'time_(secs)', 'going',
       'classifications', 'race_date', 'race_time', 'draw', 'position',
       'horse', 'dtn', 'dtw', 'jockey', 'jockey_claim', 'trainer', 'age',
       'dslr', 'dam', 'sire', 'bf_decimal_sp', 'won', 'place', 'orm',
       'time_secs', 'runs_before', 'distance_to_winner_lto'],
      dtype='object')
```

An example of the question(s) I want to ask of this df would be iterating through and finding all instances where the value in the class column for the time before (based on the date column) is < the current row.

I am struggling to write a function for this where I can make it horse agnostic and have it just iterate through the df looking for all horse name matches and comparing the class column ordered by date.

I apologise if I've not done a good job of explaining that.

Comment: a sample of your data with your intended output would go a long way.

Comment: As soon as you are able to formulate the problem comprehensibly and reproducible, you will probably be able to solve it yourself: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)